# Lebesgue integration theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So my question is, we define the simple function to take finite values, does it change a lot of what we have established for Lebesgue integration theory if we define the simple function to take instead countably infinite values?

Comment: Shouldn't it be lebasgue

Comment: There's no real incentive, and only hassle. With a "finitely many values" simple function the integral is just a finite sum; with a "countably many values" simple function, it's an infinite sum already and you have to worry about convergence issues etc.

Comment: I agree, making it infinite would probably make it more complicated, but i don't know if it adds or change some nature of it

Comment: The theory would turn out the same, but be more annoying to develop.

Comment: i would imagine so

Comment: It's not really much different. You just prove that "finite valued" simple functions are dense in your integrable "countable valued" simple functions and then it's the same theory. But that step was just a waste of your time, since the "finite valued" simple functions are already dense in the whole space you're trying to access.

Comment: I see. That's a lot more precise way to put it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can define simple functions as those who take countably infinite values. When the range is finite the function is called simple-finite function. In general, every
measurable function is uniform-limit of simple functions, but not necessarily uniform limit of simple-finite function. What is very easy to show is that every measurable function $f$ is pointwise limit of simple finite functions. This last result is enough to develop several important results in measure and integration theory.